# RStudio character encoding

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, rstudio

I am trying to view characters of multiple of languages in RStudio. What I find unusual is I am able to view these in the console, but not in the viewer. UTF-8 encoded characters appear like 'U+3042', 'U+500B', etc. in the viewer.

Is there a way to get the viewer to display the actual characters instead of the encoded character?

Here are a couple of images showing what I mean -

1. In console: https://ibb.co/T0681H7
2. In viewer: https://ibb.co/QnxF25c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in RStudio. Feel free to comment/upvote here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4193